# How transactions are converted to blocks in blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, bitcoin

In bitcoin world,
Eric sends 1Bitcoin to Bob
This transaction is stored as ledger in nodes.

1. Is it a normal transaction data or a block ?
2. How multiple transactions are written in a block ?
3. Before miner mines a block, how transactions are stored in this block ?

Comment: There's a separate Stack Exchange site for this, [bitcoin.se]. Stack Overflow is only for specific questions about problems encountered while writing code.

Comment: transactions in Ethereum are stored as an array of object `Transaction` , and the result of each transaction is called `Receipt` and it is stored in another array. Then the hash on all Block info is generated and the block is stored. That's it

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain is a decentralized ledger.
In Blockchain each transaction generates a hash value.

Blockchain has a concept called a transaction pool. When we perform a transaction, this is held in a transaction pool. These transactions from transaction-pool are gathered to candidate block by a miner and later it is added to blockchain.